# error No such file or Directory found | Linux |

Tags: linux, shell

I have a Scenario

where I want to fetch the filenames which does not contain this below entire line

```
"<NAME = $$WORK_STUDENT GEN=123 VARIABLE=EXEC >"
```

**Used below command Not working as expected showing error**

```
grep -rL "<NAME = $$WORK_STUDENT GEN=123 VARIABLE=EXEC >" >> /d/notfound_list.txt
```

**Error I am getting is**

```
grep: File: No such file or directory
grep: <NAME =12234WORK_STUDENT GEN=123 VARIABLE=EXEC>: No such file or directory
```

It is not able to identify the Symbol => $$ 
instead of that it is taking some number like some process_id

How do I search this entire line any solution will be appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [man grep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) the syntax is:

> grep [OPTIONS] PATTERN [FILE...]

Then we read:

> grep searches the named input FILEs (or standard input if no files are named

What you did is:

```
 grep -rL "<NAME = $$WORK_STUDENT GEN=123 VARIABLE=EXEC >"
                                                             ^^^^^ - no file
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - PATTERN
      ^^^ - these are OPTIONS
```

You gave `grep` no files, so it waits for standard input, for anything you type. Give `grep` a file to search through or a directory it can recursively with `-r` search through.

```
 grep -rL "<NAME = $$WORK_STUDENT GEN=123 VARIABLE=EXEC >"  some_directory/ some_file.txt
```